# Finding a function with given Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Is it possible to find out what function given Fourier series describes?

I have the following problem:

Calculate 
$
\sum_{1}^{ \infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n-1}
$

I know given series is expansion of constant $\pi$/4 but I can't see a way of reverse-engineering it into this function.

Best i could come up with are following equations:

$
\frac{1}{2n-1}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)cos(nx) dx
$

$
0=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)dx
$

I don't see a way to find f(x) from them though.

Comment: Look into the Fourier expansion of $\sin(x)/x$

Comment: did you try with $f=1$ for $-\pi<x<-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $f=-1$ for $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$,  $f=1$ for $\dfrac{\pi}{2}<x<\pi$.

Comment: Who said your problem is related to Fourier series at all? Multiply the $n$'th term by $x^{2n-1}$ and go on.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can you expand on the solution? I don't see how that would let me solve the sum as even if you differentiate each term and 2n-1 cancels out I'm left with $(-1)^n*x^{2n-1} $

Also, I found another task that uses the same series and it is as follows: expand $\pi$/4 into fourier series and using the expansion calculate the infinite sum of a given series, so I'm pretty sure that is related to Fourier series.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - I know the function that expands into this series - it's $\pi$/4, I just don't know how to find it with only series given. Am I supposed to just remember the expansions of some common functions?

Comment: @mateusz : I am afraid that's the method if you want to sum series via Fourier series. If you use complex analysis there are more systematic methods, though.

Comment: @MateuszSzwed the Fourier series of $\pi/4$  is $\pi/4$. you should consider $\pi/4$  as a peicewise such as $\pi/4$  in $[-\pi,0]$ and $0$ in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: $$ 
\begin{align} 
\arctan(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\implies\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4} \\ 
\beta(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^x}\quad\implies\quad\beta(1)=\frac{\pi}{4} 
\end{align} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

The [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series)
$$
\ln \left( {{1 \over {1 - z}}} \right) = \ln \left( {1 + {z \over {1 - z}}} \right)
 = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{z^{\,k + 1} } \over {k + 1}}} \quad \left| {\;\left| z \right| \le 1\; \wedge \;z \ne 1} \right.
$$
converges for $|z| \le 1$, except when $z=1$, to the principal branch of $\ln(1/(1-z))$.

So it converges for $z=i$, which gives:
$$
\eqalign{
  & \ln \left( {{1 \over {1 - i}}} \right) =  - \ln \sqrt 2  + i{\pi  \over 4} =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{i^{\,k + 1} } \over {k + 1}}}
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{i^{\,2n + 1} } \over {2n + 1}}}  + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{i^{\,2n + 2} } \over {2n + 2}}}  =   \cr 
  &  =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{i^{\,2n} } \over {2n + 2}}}  + i\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{i^{\,2n} } \over {2n + 1}}}
  =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} } \over {2n + 2}}}  + i\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} } \over {2n + 1}}}  \cr} 
$$

That means
$$
\eqalign{
  & {1 \over 2}\left( {\ln \left( {{1 \over {1 - z}}} \right) - \ln \left( {{1 \over {1 - \left( { - z} \right)}}} \right)} \right)
 = {1 \over 2}\ln \left( {{{1 + z} \over {1 - z}}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {{{1 - \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} } \over {k + 1}}z^{\,k + 1} } 
 = z\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{z^{\,2n} } \over {2n + 1}}}  \cr} 
$$

Therefore, putting $z=e^{it/2}$, the expression
$$
\eqalign{
  & F(t) = {1 \over {2e^{\,i\,t/2} }}\ln \left( {{{1 + e^{\,i\,t/2} } \over {1 - e^{\,i\,t/2} }}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{e^{\,i\,n\,t} } \over {2n + 1}}}
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\cos \left( {n\,t} \right)} \over {2n + 1}}}  + i\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\sin \left( {n\,t} \right)} \over {2n + 1}}}  \cr} 
$$
will converge for all the values $0 < t < 2\pi$.

Finally, we arrive to
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & F(t)\quad \left| {\;0 < t < 2\pi } \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\cos \left( {n\,t} \right)} \over {2n + 1}}}  + i\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {{{\sin \left( {n\,t} \right)} \over {2n + 1}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2e^{\,i\,t/2} }}\ln \left( {{{1 + e^{\,i\,t/2} } \over {1 - e^{\,i\,t/2} }}} \right)
 = {1 \over {2e^{\,i\,t/2} }}\ln \left( {{{e^{\, - \,i\,t/4}  + e^{\,\,i\,t/4} } \over {e^{\, - \,i\,t/4}  - e^{\,\,i\,t/4} }}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}e^{\, - \,i\,t/2} \ln \left( {{i \over {\tan \left( {t/4} \right)}}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\left( {\cos \left( {t/2} \right) - i\sin \left( {t/2} \right)} \right)
   \left( { - \ln \left| {\tan \left( {t/4} \right)} \right| + i{\pi  \over 2}} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\left( { - \cos \left( {t/2} \right)\ln \left| {\tan \left( {t/4} \right)} \right| + {\pi  \over 2}\sin \left( {t/2} \right)} \right) +   \cr 
  &  + {i \over 2}\left( {\sin \left( {t/2} \right)\ln \left| {\tan \left( {t/4} \right)} \right| + {\pi  \over 2}\cos \left( {t/2} \right)} \right) \cr} 
}$$

Comment: @MateuszSzwed: I would like to receive your feedback: is the above what you are looking for ? or did I misunderstand your questions?